# Airflow job not Scheduling after manual Trigger

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using Airflow version 2.2.3(Latest version). My Airflow Dag is scheduled to run "@daily".
I manually triggered the Dag yesterday(2022-02-08, 09:19:22) and I expect it to be scheduled Today at 2022-02-09, 00:00:00, but the DAG was not scheduled.

From the below image
[image]

The last run was on 2022-02-08, 09:19:22 and the next run is scheduled at 2022-02-09, 00:00:00. But the time has already passed and it is 2022-02-09 06:22 UTC

DAG parameters:

```
{'catchup': False,
 'catchup_by_default': False,
 'depends_on_past': False,
 'provide_context': True,
 'retries': 1,
 'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(0, 300),
 'start_date': DateTime(2021, 12, 31, 15, 50, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))}
```

Do I need to change any parameters or config values? Please suggest

Comment: Hi! I have the same trouble. Have you somehow solved it?